# How to improve the performance of K-nn algorithm in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am having a digit recognizer data set which has column names as label, pixel0, pixel1...pixel783. pixel values vary from 0 to 255 indicating the lightness or darkness of that pixel, with higher numbers meaning darker. I have applied a simple k-NN algorithm on the test data which gives me 97% accuracy. What should I do to improve the performance further?

There are no other arguments in the data set but pixel0...pixel783. There are 28000 rows in the test data set and I have used k=10. Can I increase the value of k to improve the performance further?

Comment: Be wary of overfitting. This question might be better suited for CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0):

There are not that many parameters available for a k-NN algorithm.  Changing k may have an improvement on the performance, but it really depends on the training cases you have for the model.  Using a larger k will use some of the lesser-related training cases for evaluation, so it is difficult without trial and error.

In my own experience, k=10 has usually been a good starting point.  Another method might be to look at your inputs and see if they could be improved, but 97% is quite a good outcome.

Hope this helps!